# Не собиратся Flutter проект при подключении Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firestore, flutter

Я изучаю Flutter. Разобрался как работать с Firebase Remote Config. Но возникли проблемы при попытке написсания приложения для работы с Cloud Firestore. Используя плагин cloud_firestore (на момент написания вопроса версия была 0.10.0) я столкнулся с тем, что приложение не может собраться:

```
Note: /home/taylan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.10.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/taylan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.10.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/taylan/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.3.4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 72090 > 65536)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/54.jar, /home/taylan/AndroidStudioProjects/temp/flutter_test_app/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar
  The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
  Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Приведу само приложение ниже:

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "taylan.flutter_test_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: flutter_test_app
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.10.0
  firebase_core: "^0.3.2"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp()
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Name here'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text('Hello world')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема же описана в логах которые Вы приложили.

Если кратко:

1 Откройте `app/build.gradle` и допишите:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
dependencies { 
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

2 Создайте класс-наследник `FlutterApplication`:

```
package com.yourpackage;


import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

public class App extends FlutterApplication {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

3 Укажите его в `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"

//Вместо
//<application
//    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

И все заработает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]